# Anomally detection

Tags: matlab, optimization, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I'm writing a code to detect anomalys using Gaussian distribution.

This is the code i wrote to compute the probability density function:

```
function p = multivariateGaussian(X, mu, Sigma2)
%MULTIVARIATEGAUSSIAN Computes the probability density function of the
%multivariate gaussian distribution.
%    p = MULTIVARIATEGAUSSIAN(X, mu, Sigma2) Computes the probability 
%    density function of the examples X under the multivariate gaussian 
%    distribution with parameters mu and Sigma2. If Sigma2 is a matrix, it is
%    treated as the covariance matrix. If Sigma2 is a vector, it is treated
%    as the \sigma^2 values of the variances in each dimension (a diagonal
%    covariance matrix)
%

k = length(mu);

if (size(Sigma2, 2) == 1) || (size(Sigma2, 1) == 1)
    Sigma2 = diag(Sigma2);
end

X = bsxfun(@minus, X, mu(:)');
p = (2 * pi) ^ (- k / 2) * det(Sigma2) ^ (-0.5) * ...
    exp(-0.5 * sum(bsxfun(@times, X * pinv(Sigma2), X), 2));

end
```

My first question: are there a fastter and clever way to compute this? I have a little matlab cluster setuped here with 2 pcs, but in this case, i have no clue how to parallelize this.

My second question:In one of the matrices i using as trainning set is [42712X19700], even having 24 gb of ram, im getting out of memory error. Is it possible use a technique like random forest(slice the trainning set, and then combine de results?)? Or any other way to circumvent this problem?

I appreciate any help. Tks in advance!

Comment: I don't see any obvious speed improvements, however it is quite common for vectorized solutions to blow out of ram when you operate on matrices of that size. Would processing row by row be a solution? (If so, you can also easily wrap it in a `parfor` loop to parallelize)

Comment: what's the 'training' operation? Setting mu and sigma? If so, their sufficient statistics can be computed cumulatively

Comment: I reviewed the formulas used to make de calculations, and, as Ben said, is a cumulative sum! So will be no problem separate the trainingset in chunks and calculate in a parfor, as Dennis said! Tks guys, problem solved!

Comment: Btw are these matrices Sparse ? In which case the sparse matrix datastructure could be used.

Comment: Unfortunately they are not!

Answer (score 0):

Divide the data into small chunks and apply parfor for processing of each chunk. That is simply my choose for large scale processing. Or you might use process based parallelization and read one chunk as another process is computing on another chunk of data.